# Does ARC support dispatch queues?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I'm reading apple's documentation about "Memory Management for Dispatch Queues":

> Even if you implement a garbage-collected application, you must still retain and release your dispatch queues and other dispatch objects. Grand Central Dispatch does not support the garbage collection model for reclaiming memory.

I know that ARC is not a garbage collector but I'd like to be sure that I don't need to dispatch_retain and dispatch_release my dispatch_queue_t

Answer (score 236, accepted):

## The short answer: YES, ARC retains and releases dispatch queues.

And now for the long answer…

### If your deployment target is lower than iOS 6.0  or Mac OS X 10.8

You need to use `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release` on your queue.  ARC does not manage them.

### If your deployment target is iOS 6.0 or Mac OS X 10.8 or later

ARC will manage your queue for you.  You do not need to (and cannot) use `dispatch_retain` or `dispatch_release` if ARC is enabled.

#### Details

Starting in the iOS 6.0 SDK and the Mac OS X 10.8 SDK, every dispatch object (including a `dispatch_queue_t`) is also an Objective-C object.  This is documented in the `<os/object.h>` header file:

```
 * By default, libSystem objects such as GCD and XPC objects are declared as
 * Objective-C types when building with an Objective-C compiler. This allows
 * them to participate in ARC, in RR management by the Blocks runtime and in
 * leaks checking by the static analyzer, and enables them to be added to Cocoa
 * collections.
 *
 * NOTE: this requires explicit cancellation of dispatch sources and xpc
 *       connections whose handler blocks capture the source/connection object,
 *       resp. ensuring that such captures do not form retain cycles (e.g. by
 *       declaring the source as __weak).
 *
 * To opt-out of this default behavior, add -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 to your
 * compiler flags.
 *
 * This mode requires a platform with the modern Objective-C runtime, the
 * Objective-C GC compiler option to be disabled, and at least a Mac OS X 10.8
 * or iOS 6.0 deployment target.
```

This means you can store your queue in an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, or in a property with one of the `strong`, `weak`, `unsafe_unretained`, `assign`, or `retain` attributes.  It also means that if you refer to your queue from a block, the block will retain the queue automatically.

So **if your deployment target is at least iOS 6.0** or Mac OS X 10.8, and **you have ARC enabled**, ARC will retain and release your queue, and the compiler will flag any attempt to use `dispatch_retain` or `dispatch_release` as an error.

**If your deployment target is at least iOS 6.0** or Mac OS X 10.8, and **you have ARC disabled**, you must manually retain and release your queue, *either* by calling `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`, *or* by sending the queue `retain` and `release` messages (like `[queue retain]` and `[queue release]`).

For compatibility with old codebases, you can prevent the compiler from seeing your queue as an Objective-C object by defining `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` to `0`.  For example, you can put this in your `.pch` file (before any `#import` statements):

```
#define OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC 0
```

or you can add `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0` as a preprocessor macro in your build settings.  If you set `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` to `0`, ARC will **not** retain or release your queue for you, and you will have to do it yourself using `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`.

Comment: Note, however, that the new change designates dispatch objects as Objective-C objects.  Thus, even if ARC is disabled, these objects will automatically be retained if captured by a block -- just like all other Objective-C objects.

Comment: There's an interesting edge case. If your library deploys to iOS 5.1 and your app to 6.0 and you're using ARC, you need to `dispatch_release` **and** `NULL` the object in your 5.1 `dealloc` code. Otherwise, something (code generated by the compiler? The runtime itself?) will try to release the object a second time.

Comment: Do i need to dispatch other source objects I create when using Mac OS 10.7?

Comment: You must manually retain/release all GCD objects under OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 23):

Just a follow up here... If your minimum deployment target is iOS 6, ARC now manages them.

Comment: This also applies to Mountain Lion. If your deployment target is iOS 6 or Mountain Lion, you cannot (by default) use dispatch_release since that is a macro which sends a release message to the object which is not allowed under ARC.