# Release instance resources once and only once?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I need to protect some code to invalidate a serial queue, in an `-invalidate` method, so that these codes would be run once, like the `dispatch_once` in the singleton paradigm.

My intuition is:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isValid) BOOL valid;
@property(nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
...
- (void)invalidate {
    if ([self isValid]){
        dispatch_sync(self.serialQueue, ^{
            if ([self isValid]) {
                _valid = NO;
                // relinquish resources here
            }
        });
        if (self.serialQueue) {
            dispatch_release (self.serialQueue);
        }
    }
}
```

This `-invalidate` method would be called either explicitly or by `-dealloc`. And I want to make sure that the resources would be relinquished once and only once.

Is this implementation thread-safe?

Is it a better way to implement a `dispatch_once` block in a per-instance manner?

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_once_t invalidated;
...
- (void)invalidate {
    dispatch_once(&_invalidated, ^{
        dispatch_sync(logQueue, ^{
            // double check
            if (self.isValid) {
                self.valid = NO;
                // relinquish things
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dealloc already handles this for you.

Comment: I cannot rely on `dealloc` because it is not guaranteed what time it is actually called. I need to release some resources, e.g. a file handle, before removing the file from disk. These should be done like a transaction. And I'd rather invalidate the instance which held the resource than release the instance itself.

Comment: If you have multiple instances managing the same resource you have bigger problems than dispatch_once.

Comment: @stackmonster: "dealloc already handles this for you" - Only on iOS 6/OS X 10.8 or later, see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues. Also I assumed from the question that there are other resources to release, but I may of course be wrong.

Comment: I may have multiple(, typically 2) instances referring to the same instance that manages the resource, hence I want to keep it thread-safe by enforcing a serial dispatch queue.

Comment: most of these discussions just muddy the waters.  If you attempt to manage a single resource with multiple instances and need a moment certain deallocation of resources you are reimplementing garbage collection.  Alloc and dealloc properly, encapsulate resources properly and you wont have these problems.

Comment: Maybe I should revise the design like using weak reference than strong ones to decouple multiple-to-one ownerships.

Answer (score 1):

If `invalidate` does not need to be thread-safe, you can just do

```
- (void)invalidate {
    if ([self isValid]) {
        _valid = NO;
        // relinquish resources here
    }
}
```

because setting `_valid = NO` already guarantees that the function is called only once.

Things get a little more complicated if the invalidation must be done in a thread-safe manner. You could use `dispatch_once`. The disadvantage is that this really works only once. So if you validate your object again later, invalidation will not work anymore.

Alternatively, you can use one of the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) methods, e.g. `@synchronized`:

```
- (void)invalidate {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if ([self isValid]) {
            _valid = NO;
            // relinquish resources here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the use of `@synchronized(){}` still recommended?

Comment: @ZhangChn: It is one of the synchronization methods in Apple's "Threading Programming Guide". If you have information that it is no longer recommended, I would be interested in a reference.