# Do ARC accessors handle GCD memory management automatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ARC support dispatch queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues)

When declaring a GCD property like so:

```
@property (assign, atomic) dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
```

Do the accessors get synthesised with appropriate calls to `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`, or do I still need to write my own manual retains/releases?

Comment: If your deployment target is at least iOS 6, then ARC manages this automatically, see e.g. this excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619055/1187415. But of course you must declare the propery as "strong" to get release/retain calls generated.