# Why is ARC complaining about dispatch_queue_create and dispatch_release in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I declared a property to reference a GCD queue:

```
@property (assign) dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
```

In the init method of a class I create a serial queue:

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

ARC complains: "Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment"

Must I use __bridge_transfer?

In -dealloc I am releasing the queue:

```
dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

Again, ARC complains: "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'"

I find this confusing because this is a C function call and thought queues are C objects for which I must take care of memory management myself! Since when does ARC handle the C-objects for me?

Answer (score 39):

In iOS 6 you can cmd+click dispatch_queue_t and see this:

```
/*
 * By default, dispatch objects are declared as Objective-C types when building
 * with an Objective-C compiler. This allows them to participate in ARC, in RR
 * management by the Blocks runtime and in leaks checking by the static
 * analyzer, and enables them to be added to Cocoa collections.
 * See <os/object.h> for details.
 */
```

So simply use strong in the property (unless the queue is referenced elsewhere and you really want a weak reference).

Before iOS 6 you have to do memory management yourself using dispatch_retain and dispatch_release. Doing this in iOS 6 will throw a compiler error.

Comment: So ... my code in iOS 5 that was 100% correct ... is now incorrect memory management? Awesome! Also: great compiler messages (sigh).

Comment: Just a question, what does RR mean?

Comment: @Ricardo Retain-Release. From Apple docs, where they use the term MRR to refer to manual retain-release.

Comment: @Jano Thanks. I know MRC (manual reference counting, the counterpart of ARC) but never heard about RR.

Answer (score 10):

This error message will come if you are using **iOS 6** SDK.

In the `iOS 6.0 SDK` and the `Mac OS X 10.8 SDK`, every dispatch object is also a part of objective C. So you don't want to worry about the memory, ARC will manage the memory of `dispatch_queue`.

Please refer the [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/517) for details.

Comment: so basically, i don't need to set a property for dispatch_queue. All I need to do is to use it wherever i want in the code. Am i right to say this?

Comment: I mean you don't want to call dispatch_retain and dispatch_release in iOS 6. ARC'll manage the memory

Comment: how about this: ARC complains: "Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment"?

Comment: Never assign an retained object to unsafe_unretained object. That is a normal case to all objects not only for dispatch objects

Comment: so the solution to that part, is to remove the assign in the property declaration?

Comment: So the warning is spurious?

Answer (score 3):

You should not insist on using `assign`. You can use:

```
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
```

or even

```
@property dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
```

with no warning.

Answer (score 1):

The magic `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release` functions are defined based on lots of conditions.

Bottom line in my tests:
 - if you deploy for sdk 5, use them and all is well
 - if you deploy for sdk >= 6 , do not even think of them, just treat everything as object

You can see a better explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues?rq=1