# dispatch_release() in ios6

Tags: ios6, release, grand-central-dispatch

In iOS 6 dispatch_queue is managed by ARC . The complier complains if I use dispatch_release.

If I develop in ios6 sdk , but I still want to deploy the app in ios5, is that ok if I do not write dispatch_release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set your deployment target to iOS 5 (or iOS 5.1, or any version earlier than iOS 6.0), the compiler will let you use `dispatch_release` without complaining.  It only complains if your deployment target is set to iOS 6.0 or later.  The SDK version doesn't matter.  Only the deployment target version matters.

For full details, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619055/77567).