# AFNetworking 2.0 ERROR:Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Updated my project to `AFNetworking`, Xcode show this error:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
```

Property with '`retain or strong`' attribute must be of object type.

I cannot understand why the official example there is no error warning?

Comment: Short answer: make sure that Pod which depends on AFNetworking 2.0 has `platform :ios, '6.0'` spec. I had a Pod (with s.dependency AFNetworking) specified for `platform :ios`, therefore build phases for this Pod had `DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0` flag for the file, which imported AFNetworking and [dispatch_queue_t happened to be opted-out from being an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues).

Comment: The above comment doesn't work for me. To solve the compile error, I changed the build setting `iOS Deployment Target` to `iOS 6.0`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I get it, because I test on iOS5, dispatch_queue_t is objcet begin at iOS6

Comment: Hi,already at iOS6 but the same error,just don't know why.

Comment: updated it too to iOS in the deployment target, but still doesn't work. I know this thread has been a bit inactive lately, but anybody has an alternative to suggest?

Comment: were you able to fix this? my target is already 6.0

Comment: It might be too old, however I fixed it with this POD option:platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.3'. Seems like recent SignalR works only with AfNetworking lib v 1.3.3