# Do you need to call dispatch_group_release under ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

On modern iOS, `dispatch_queue_t` values are Objective-C objects and are managed by ARC so it's not necessary to call `dispatch_release` on them. Is the same true for `dispatch_group_t` values and their corresponding `dispatch_group_release` call?

Comment: Be careful of what you are asking, the answer of the question in your question's title is different from the answer of the one in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true for all subclasses of `dispatch_object_t` including `dispatch_group_t`.

There is actually no `dispatch_group_release` call, the only C release API for these objects is `dispatch_release`.

See headerdoc in `dispatch/object.h` for more details.

Answer (score 3):

No, if your deployment target is iOS 6+ then you do not have to call the release function for any object managed by GCD.

This question has already been asked several times but the most complete answer is here:

[Does ARC support dispatch queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues)