# dispatch_release compiler error when upgrading deployment target

Tags: ios, deployment, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I'm told to upgrade the deployment target of an iOS app from iOS 5.1.1 to iOS 6.0. I had several `dispatch_queue_t` variables in code with corresponding `dispatch_release` function calls. Compiler did not complain until now that I've raised the deployment target.

I've read several posts related to this (e.g. [Does ARC support dispatch queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues/8619055#8619055)) where it is said that `dispatch_release` is not needed anymore starting from iOS 6.0, but... do I need to replace such function call with another, or have I simply to remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can simply remove them. Compiler does automatically emit code to release dispatch queues and other GCD objects as Objective-C objects. You might need to modify a bit to release dispatch queues if there is retain cycle.

Or you can keep `dispatch_release` calling with -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 compiler flag [as you read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues/8619055#8619055).