# Use dispatch_after delay inside a loop

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, timer, delay, grand-central-dispatch

Is there any way to use `dispatch_after` within a loop?  I have the delay function below:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

I want to execute it inside of a loop like this:

```
while true {
    self.delay(1.0) {
        // Do something repeatedly
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get it working.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you want a task to be executed timely like this you should use a regular timer

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer-type dispatch source to call the closure repeatedly. Example:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

func withTimerInterval(seconds: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) -> dispatch_source_t {
    let source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue())
    let interval = Int64(seconds * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_source_set_timer(source, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval), UInt64(interval), 20 * NSEC_PER_MSEC)
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, block)
    dispatch_resume(source)
    return source
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let timer = withTimerInterval(1) {
    print("hello again")
}
```

Cancel the timer like this:

```
dispatch_source_cancel(timer)
```

Comment: Can I do this outside of a playground?

Comment: Yes, you can copy the `withTimerInterval` function into your project and use it in a real app.

Comment: It says `extra argument in call` on the `withTimerInterval` line

Comment: @robmayoff Do I need to add dispatch_release(source) after canceling the dispatch source when coding in Swift?

Comment: @LeoDabus Not to speak for Rob Mayoff, but unlike a `NSTimer`, you have to keep a strong reference to the dispatch source timer in order for the repeating timer to continue to work. But when you relinquish your last strong reference to it, the source is automatically released.

Comment: @LeoDabus You cannot call `dispatch_release` at all in Swift, or [in Objective-C with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619055/77567).

Comment: @Teldridge11 Edit your question to include your new code that calls `withTimerInterval`.

Comment: @robmayoff I asked because I was reading Canceling a Dispatch Source at  Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html

Comment: The programming guide is out of date with respect to reference counting of GCD objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (;;sleep(1)) {
    print("Hello Again");
}
```

*Note, this will lock your main thread every (1 second + 1 cycle) for 1 second. If this is an issue please run your <s>while</s>for loop in a separate thread, sleep that NSThread instead, and simply `dispatch_get_main_queue()` inside the for loop.